# Number of route in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

Is there a way I could calculate the number of routes in a list of lists? The rule is to pick an element in each sub-list to form a list, and the value in the new list is ascending. (The length of the list or sub-list is not fixed)

e.q.
a list is

```
[[1, 10], [5, 16], [3, 20]]
```

There are three ways to fulfill the requirement:

```
[1, 5, 20]
[1, 16, 20]
[10, 16, 20]
```

Comment: An interesting problem.  Do you need the routes themselves or just the count?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @wim I just need the result, what I currently have is not good, I found all the possibilities then validate if it is ascending.

Comment: google "dynamic programming".  I think this is a nice use-case.

Comment: @wim Thanks for your advice, I will use this case to strengthen my knowledge of dp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use some sort of recursion based on the starting element. For efficiency, add [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), which [can be done in Python quite easily](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php) (see esp. [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) as pointed out by @abarnert in the comments below).

Say you have a function like so:

```
def num_routes_starting_with(list_of_lists, starting_elem)
```

where `starting_elem` is the starting element of the route. That is, each element in the route taken from `list_of_lists[0]` must be at least larger than `starting_elem`.

Then there are two points:

1. It's not so hard to code `num_routes_starting_with` recursively. Because for any element in `list_of_lists[0]` which you use (which is simple to find - just check if it is not smaller than `starting_elem`), you just need to call `routes_starting_with` with `list_of_lists[1: ]` and `starting_elem` replaced by the element you just used. You need to return the sum of the return values.
2. Once you have `num_routes_starting_with`, it's easy to wrap it in some toplevel `routes` - simply:

a. If  `list_of_lists` is empty, the answer is 0).

b. If it is not, choose the smallest element in `list_of_lists[0]`, subtract from it 1, and call `numroutes_starting_with` with `list_of_lists` and the subtraction result.

---

Here's how it looks altogether:

```
def num_routes(list_of_lists):
    if len(list_of_lists) == 0:
        return 0

    return num_routes_starting_with(list_of_lists, min(list_of_lists[0]) - 1)

# You should add here some memoization decorator, something like:
# @memoized
def num_routes_starting_with(list_of_lists, starting_elem):
    if not list_of_lists:
        return 1

    s = 0
    for e in list_of_lists[0]:
        if e > starting_elem:
            s += num_routes_starting_with(list_of_lists[1: ], e)
    return s

list_of_lists = [[1, 10], [5, 16], [3, 20]]
print num_routes(list_of_lists)
```

Comment: Thanks! it's helpful to see such feedback.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: You should be able to just use `functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)` for your memoization here.